# Appending to a list based on criteria but avoiding adding duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, append

I am trying to create a sabermetrically optimized lineup order for MLB teams based on each player's statistics. I have a dataframe of stats where I am pulling from and adding to an empty list in order of importance, and then re-ordering the list to create a batting lineup.

Here is how the batting order goes:

1. Highest OBP
2. Highest OPS
3. 2nd Highest SLG
4. 2nd Highest OPS
5. Highest SLG
6. 3rd Highest OPS
7. 4th Highest OPS
8. 5th Highest OPS
9. 6th Highest OPS

Now - the importance in what order a player gets assigned a spot in the lineup is also important to optimize. That order is 2,4,1,5,3,6,7,8,9. Therefore, the 2nd spot in the lineup is most important, so the individual with the highest OPS should be added to the list first, so that he is removed from being added to any other spots in the lineup based on his stats.

So, I have an empty list where I start pulling the most important players by their stats, and then deleting them from the dataframe so I can pull again without choosing them twice.

Here is my code:

```
opt_lineup = []
opt_lineup.append((chosen_team[chosen_team['OPS']==chosen_team['OPS'].max()]['Player']))
chosen_team.drop(chosen_team['OPS'].idxmax(), inplace = True)
opt_lineup.append((chosen_team[chosen_team['OPS']==chosen_team['OPS'].max()]['Player']))
chosen_team.drop(chosen_team['OPS'].idxmax(), inplace = True)
opt_lineup.append((chosen_team[chosen_team['OBP']==chosen_team['OBP'].max()]['Player']))
chosen_team.drop(chosen_team['OBP'].idxmax(), inplace = True)
opt_lineup.append((chosen_team[chosen_team['SLG']==chosen_team['SLG'].max()]['Player']))
chosen_team.drop(chosen_team['SLG'].idxmax(), inplace = True)
opt_lineup.append((chosen_team[chosen_team['SLG']==chosen_team['SLG'].max()]['Player']))
chosen_team.drop(chosen_team['SLG'].idxmax(), inplace = True)
chosen_team.head(30)
```

The issue I have is that when I append a player to the empty list, if two players tie for the highest stat, then they both get added to the list, when I only want to take the first.

Essentially - I'm looking for a solution similar to `keep = 'first'` when using `.drop()`, but for when appending to a list.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So your issue is that multiple players have the highest stat, and you only want to add the first. The list.max() method returns the highest value in a list, and the list.index() method finds the first index of a given value in a list. So let's find the max ops value(for example) and find the first index of that value in the list for the index we will use.

Here's an example in code:

```
ops_list = [400, 500, 500, 243]

max_ops = max(ops_list)#finds max value in the above list

max_index = ops_list.index(max_obs)#gets first index with the max value we found

battingorder[1] = players[max_index]#Assuming battingorder is defined and players has synced indices with the stat lists
```

EDIT: make sure to remove the index from each list after adding it to the batting order, otherwise you may get repeat players.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure to choose only one entry (the first one) of the max entries instead of choosing all entries that match the max value, you can amend your codes to use [`idxmax()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) similar to what you do for `.drop`.

You can see from the official document of [`idxmax()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) that:

> If multiple values equal the maximum, the first row label with that
> value is returned.

```
opt_lineup = []
opt_lineup.append(chosen_team.loc[chosen_team['OPS'].idxmax(), 'Player'])   #changed
chosen_team.drop(chosen_team['OPS'].idxmax(), inplace = True)
opt_lineup.append(chosen_team.loc[chosen_team['OPS'].idxmax(), 'Player'])   #changed
chosen_team.drop(chosen_team['OPS'].idxmax(), inplace = True)
opt_lineup.append(chosen_team.loc[chosen_team['OBP'].idxmax(), 'Player'])   #changed
chosen_team.drop(chosen_team['OBP'].idxmax(), inplace = True)
opt_lineup.append(chosen_team.loc[chosen_team['SLG'].idxmax(), 'Player'])   #changed
chosen_team.drop(chosen_team['SLG'].idxmax(), inplace = True)
opt_lineup.append(chosen_team.loc[chosen_team['SLG'].idxmax(), 'Player'])   #changed
chosen_team.drop(chosen_team['SLG'].idxmax(), inplace = True)
chosen_team.head(30)
```

Note that I have also changed your codes to use [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) in the format e.g.

```
chosen_team.loc[chosen_team['OPS'].idxmax(), 'Player']
```

instead of using the format:

```
chosen_team[chosen_team['OPS'].idxmax()]['Player']
```

This is for a better practice to avoid the SettingWithCopyWarning and also may get better execution time / memory utilization.